# Android Gradient border?

Tags: android, gradient, radial-gradients

Task:

Want to accomplish gradient BORDER...

Start color starts from blue circle edge and end color ends on red ring edge.

[image]

I tried with shape oval, and ring and radial gradient.
I need gradient that starts from edge of the circle (not from the centre) and expand to the end color.
I am interested is it even possible to do that with radial gradient.
What am I missing?

So far I made it like this:

```
<!-- Added shadow -->
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:width="85dp"
        android:height="85dp">

        <shape
            android:shape="ring"
            android:thickness="10dp"
            android:useLevel="false">

            <gradient
                android:endColor="@android:color/transparent"
                android:gradientRadius="37.5dp"
                android:startColor="@color/colorBlack"
                android:type="radial"></gradient>
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item
        android:width="64dp"
        android:height="64dp"
        android:left="11dp"
        android:top="11dp">

        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimaryBlue" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

OUTPUT:

[image]

Original problem is not solved.
The main problem is that radial gradient starts from the centre of the circle and not from the edge.

Any more ideas?

Comment: Not understand your question properly. take a look at https://ibb.co/wYxLP8F Do you search like this?

Comment: I am looking similiar to my output image, where start color is black and end color is transparent. Where start color starts from blue circle edge. For example for your output it should be from white to red.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that you want what can be described as a corona around the disk with the disk a solid color and the corona starting with the color black at the disk's edge and transitioning to transparency radially.

I think you will need to implement a drawable for the corona with a [RadialGradient](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/RadialGradient) using the [constructors](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/RadialGradient#RadialGradient(float,%20float,%20float,%20int%5B%5D,%20float%5B%5D,%20android.graphics.Shader.TileMode)) that allows the specification of colors and color stops from the center of the disk.

Mark Allison has a blog post entitled [RadialGradient – Gradients](https://blog.stylingandroid.com/radialgradient-gradients/) that discusses the use of *RadialGradients* and their implementation.

You can look at a similar implementation that is transparent in the center and starts with black at the edge of the disk and transitions to a separate color. You would have to compute the starting position of the black as a fraction of the overall size of the image.

---

---

The following is a custom drawable that produces the desired effect:

```
class CoronaDrawable : Drawable() {
    private val mPaint = Paint()
    private var mRadius = 0f
    private val mColors =
        intArrayOf(Color.TRANSPARENT, Color.TRANSPARENT, Color.BLACK, Color.BLACK and 0xFFFFFF)
    private val mStops = floatArrayOf(0f, 0.85f, 0.85f, 1.0f)

    override fun onBoundsChange(bounds: Rect) {
        super.onBoundsChange(bounds)
        mRadius = min(bounds.width(), bounds.height()) / 2f
        mPaint.shader = shaderFactory(mRadius, mRadius, mColors, mStops)
    }

    override fun draw(c: Canvas) {
        c.drawCircle(mRadius, mRadius, mRadius, mPaint)
    }

    override fun setAlpha(alpha: Int) {
    }

    override fun setColorFilter(filter: ColorFilter?) {
    }

    override fun getOpacity(): Int {
        return PixelFormat.OPAQUE
    }

    private fun shaderFactory(centerX: Float, centerY: Float, colors: IntArray, stops: FloatArray) =
        RadialGradient(
            centerX, centerY, min(centerX, centerY), colors, stops, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP
        )
}
```

which looks like this in the Android Studio layout designer as the background to a simple *View*:

[image]

The key take-away here is that the blank area in the center is set to transition from transparent to transparent or, otherwise, no change. This gives the empty center. At 85% of the radius the color abruptly changes to black and transitions to a transparent black.

For API 24+, you can place this drawable into a drawable resource file as follows and use it like a regular drawable.

**corona.xml**

```
<drawable class="com.example.radialgradientwithstops.CoronaDrawable"/>
```

You will have to determine how best to incorporate this drawable into your layer list or other means of presentation in your app.

Comment: Brilliant answer.
Yes this is actually what the task was and what I was looking for, and background for APIs below 24 can be set programatically so it can be done that way without resource folder.
I wanted to give +50 reputation, to this answer, accidentally gave to another answer and can not revoke it.

Comment: @I.Step Glad to hear it. I am wondering why the bounty was given to another answer and not this one if this is the accepted one.

Comment: Once more, I am sorry I hope the same mistake will not be made twice.

Comment: I didn't read your entire first comment or you subsequently edited it. No worries, though.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, using gradient type "sweep":

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:width="85dp"
        android:height="85dp">

        <shape
            android:shape="oval">

            <gradient
                android:endColor="@android:color/transparent"
                android:startColor="@color/black"
                android:type="sweep" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item
        android:width="64dp"
        android:height="64dp"
        android:left="11dp"
        android:top="11dp">

        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="@color/blue" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: The result is what you described above. Gradient start and end in the stroke. If it's not what you want then pls describe it clearer

Comment: Oh yes you are right the question can be understood in two ways.
I will edit it, but original intention was to make some kind of linear gradient from blue circle edge to the red circle edge.

Comment: This answer accidentaly got the bounty, my mistake, stay strong.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<!-- Drop Shadow -->
<item>
    <shape android:shape="oval">
        <padding
            android:bottom="1dp"
            android:left="1dp"
            android:right="1dp"
            android:top="1dp" />

        <solid android:color="#00CCCCCC" />

        <corners android:radius="3dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item>
    <shape android:shape="oval">
        <padding
            android:bottom="1dp"
            android:left="1dp"
            android:right="1dp"
            android:top="1dp" />

        <solid android:color="#10CCCCCC" />

        <corners android:radius="3dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item>
    <shape android:shape="oval">
        <padding
            android:bottom="1dp"
            android:left="1dp"
            android:right="1dp"
            android:top="1dp" />

        <solid android:color="#20CCCCCC" />

        <corners android:radius="3dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item>
    <shape android:shape="oval">
        <padding
            android:bottom="1dp"
            android:left="1dp"
            android:right="1dp"
            android:top="1dp" />

        <solid android:color="#30CCCCCC" />

        <corners android:radius="3dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item>
    <shape android:shape="oval">
        <padding
            android:bottom="1dp"
            android:left="1dp"
            android:right="1dp"
            android:top="1dp" />

        <solid android:color="#50CCCCCC" />

        <corners android:radius="3dp" />
    </shape>
</item>

<!-- Background Color (white) -->
<item>
    <shape android:shape="oval">
        <solid android:color="@android:color/holo_blue_dark" />

        <corners android:radius="3dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

But I recommend using a drawable with Oval Shape and elevation.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape android:shape="oval">
        <solid android:color="@android:color/white"/>
    </shape>
</item>
</layer-list>

android:elevation="@dimen/elevation_fab"
```

Otherwise, FAB is also an Ideal recommendation.

Comment: Elevation does not work with oval shapes, probably it would work with material fab button, but answer from @Cheticamp is tested and works with custom color, so I would make it as answered.